# Visual Studio Cordova - Very slow to load any plugin

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013

Using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 with Cordova CTP3.1. When I try to add any of the core plugins, VS goes into an 'almost hung' state for a good 5 minutes or so. I.e. it becomes very, very slow to respond to any mouse clicks on the window; the loading plugin status bar moves very slowly in an extremely jerky manner. Basically I cant do anything at all with the VS window for at least 5 minutes. First couple of times I though it was totally hung and killed VS, until I realized if I left it alone for long enough it would eventually succeed. CPU and network load is minimal. Any idea whats causing this, it can't possibly be normal.

Comment: I experience the same thing. You're not alone. It does eventually respond, but only after it's installed the plugin. This also happens on VS 2015 CTP6, which has Cordova tools installed. I wonder if clearing Apache Cordova cache in VS options menu won't help. Just my two cents.

Comment: I am having the same issue and have noticed that different plugins are slower to install than others.  For instance, on my machine, the BarcodeScanner takes FOREVER to install (actively installing as of this comment, going for over an hour now...), but the statusbar plugin only took a minute or two. This happens whether you install the plugin from Git or locally as well as installing the from the Core plugins available in VS.